# Binding Datagrid row number

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have an object with an Order property I want to bind it in my datagrid. Is it possible ? I would like to change the order in a datagrid and use it in my object (With order property). Can I do it with binding ?

[Edit]

```
public class MyObject
{
...
    public int Order {get; set;}
...
}
```

And I want to bind this property with Index of my row.

Comment: *Is it possible ?* well not unless you try

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question, Do you mean this Order property is for rows sorting?

Comment: What I want exactly is that order changes will be binded to my Order property of my object to be saved into the database

Answer (score 0):

OK, still not really clear, but I'll try to provide some answer...
This is how I understand a question: you have a property of type `Order`', named 'Order' and want to edit this property in a data grid, for example using a Combo

Suppose you have an entity class like this (all code - just examples, because I don't know exact classes you have):

```
class Something : EntityBase {
    ................

    public int Order { get; set; }

    ................

}
```

And it wrapped with data model like:

```
public SomethingModel : EntitydataModelBase<Something> {

     ................

     public int Order {
         get {
             return this.Entity.Order;
         }
         set {
             if (this.Entity.Order == value) return;
             this.Entity.Order = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged("Order");
         }
     }

     ................

}
```

Also, there is a view model for a screen with your data grid, like this:

```
public SomethingListViewModel : ViewModelBase {


    ................


    public IList<SomethingModel> _Items;

    public IList<SomethingModel> Items {
        get {
           return _Items;
        }
        private set {
           if (_Items == value) return;
           _Items = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
    ................

}
```

And finally your XAML:

```
   ................

<Grid x:Name="gridContainer"> <!-- We will use this name to make a reference in binding expression --!>

   <DataGrid
       ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
       <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!-- "Actually, don't remember a name of class for tempolated column" -->
            <DataGridTemplatedColumn
                 Header="Order">
                 <DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <TextBox
                              Text="{Binding Order, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                     </DataTemplate>
                 </DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplatedColumn>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>

   ................
```

Hope this will help, if it won't, please provide your example code, and I'll try to add some example based on it

Comment: I don't have VS now, so, sorry if there are mistakes in somewhere code

Comment: No Order it's just an integer property gives the rank. I edit my post with some code.

Comment: I've just changed my answer according to this. Actually... just read "with Index of my row", hm... if so, my answer is wrong. Let me think.

Comment: I think, I finally understand what you mean:) But its better to calculate this property in view model, I don't know anything like DataRow.RowIndex and don't think this is good idea to calculate Orde3r by OneWayToSource data binding or something like this. Please provide a code which loads your analog of Items property in my comment, and I'll think how to implement order calculation

Comment: Try to look at DataGridRow.AlternationIndex - maybe it handles what you want

Comment: not sure how to bind to this property, lets try: <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" x:Key="SomeKey"><Setter Property="AlternationIndex" Value="{Binding Order, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/></Style>. But I'm really not sure about this, please let me know if it works or not